# CGAffineTransformMakeScale Linker Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, transform

I have this line:

`imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);`

I want to flip my UIImageView horizontally and tried this line above, however it is giving me a linker error and can't work out the issue.

Can someone please help me fix this or find an alternative way of flipping my UIImageView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are linking against CoreGraphics. In your project, go to Build Phases and look under "Link Binary with Libraries" and check for "CoreGraphics.framework".

If that is not the issue, pls copy/paste the linker error into your question.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ta da! Worked, thanks. Something I can look out of run future. I had the core graphics framework in the left sidebar in my Frameworks folder but it wasn't in the list on the Build Phases page, so adding fixed the error! Thanks.